# Timer in Java which goes up

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am doing developing a quiz program.

I want to have a timer that goes up by one second until the person doing the quiz hit the submit answer button.

I have everything other than the timer worked out and I just wanted to know how to add the timer and make it stop when the submit answer button was hit.

Comment: Well, you know that you need a Timer. I presume you're using Swing. So, have you read the javadoc of javax.swing.Timer?

Comment: Clarify please -- is this a Swing related question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Swing since you mentioned button press, you can do this way-

```
private long startTime, endTime;
private Timer timer;

// When you need to start your timer, do-
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (timer == null) {
    timer = new Timer(100, this);
    timer.start();
} else {
    timer.restart()
}

// When the button is pressed
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
timer.stop();

double totalSeconds = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;

// To know how long it's been running-
long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
```

**Reference:** [Oracle's How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new thread that increments a number and then `Thread.sleep(1000);` in a loop. I'd admit this isn't the best way but it can be used for most cases. Without knowing the code to implement such a thing into is like guessing.

Answer (score 0):

A timer or a stopwatch? To just count the time it took the user to hit submit, you could do this:

```
// when they start the quiz question
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// when they hit submit
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

// difference is how long they took
long time = finish - start;
System.out.println("You took " + time + " milliseconds");
```

Keep in mind, the time they took will be in milliseconds. You can convert that to seconds if you want (there are 1000 milliseconds in 1 second).